# How to split string into substrings of consecutive vowels?

Tags: python

I have a long string of letters, I have to take all the substrings made by consecutive values and return the longest one. I had an idea to to it with regex but then I realized i never really touched regex before and I'm way over my head. Is there any way to do it without regex?

I was thinking about (but I don't know if it's possible) creating a for loop that will add every consecutive vowel to internal counter and then when the next letter is consonant it will append all collected letters so far to the list. But I'm stuck on this a little bit, some tips might be helpful (I don't want outright answer).

Comment: How can we give tips when we don't know where you are stuck? Some code would really help here.

Comment: Include sample inputs and outputs along with the code you have worked on so far.

Comment: You are right, I;m still new to Stack overflow and coding in general, next time I'l be more precise but meanwhile I got the right answer myself

Comment: I was stuck on the general concept. I'm new to programming so sometimes I have general understanding of what I would like my code to do, but don't know how to proceed with writing said code. I wasn't even sure if it's possible without regex, but I managed to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so just typing out what I intend to do made something in my mind "click" and suddenly it became obvious.:)

So sample inputs look like this:

Test.assert_equals(solve("ultrarevolutionariees"),3)

3 is the length of the longest consecutive vowel substring

And my code looks like this, I can'b believe it's so simple. In my mind it was complicated but just typing it shine new light on it, fantastic feeling :)

```
def solve(s):
  substrings = []
  vowels = 'aeiou'
  current_sub = ""
  for letter in s:
      if letter in vowels:
          current_sub += letter
      else:
          substrings.append(current_sub)
          current_sub = ""
  x = [len(x) for x in substrings]
  return max(x)
```

Comment: Now when I look at it I realized I could just compare each new substring with what is already stored in substrings and if it's longer then change the content of substring to current_sub, this way I don't have to iterate all over the input just to assign lengths.

Answer (score 0):

This is not posted as an acceptable answer, but too long for the comments...

Here is one approach as a script, convert to Python.

```
$ echo asdfasenaseadsfiaiieaaadfaeadaed |   # sample input
  grep -oE '[aeiou]+'                   |   # extract consecutive vowels
  awk '{print length "\t" $1}'          |   # add length to sort by
  sort -nr                              |   # sort descending order, numerically
  sed 1q                                |   # take the first, which is the max
  cut -f2                                   # remove the length 

iaiieaaa
```